# Как сделать вывод на страницу в ассоциации rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Только начал изучать ruby on rails, делаю список задач. Имеются названия групп задач `project` и собственно сами задачи `todo`, которые привязанны к группам. 
`index.html.erb` выводит только название групп задач и все задачи, непринадлежащие к конкретным группам:`

```
<% @projects.each do |t| %>
                <td><%= t.title %></td>
                <br> </br>
            <% @todos.each do |todo| %>
            <td><%= todo.text %></td>
                        <br> </br>
                <% end %>
            </div>
    <% end %>`
```

Как вывести информацию о названии группы и задачи принадлежащие только этой группе после названия? (Ассоциации настроены, необходима помощь именно с `index.html.erb`)

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <tr><strong><%= project.title %></strong></tr>
  <% project.todos.each do |todo| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= todo.text %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Почитайте о методах, которые добавляются при объявлении связи `has_many`,  в [документации](http://rusrails.ru/active-record-associations#metody-dobavlyaemye-has_many).

Comment: Я уже пробовал сделать вывод подобным образом, однако появляется ошибка undefined method todos, хотя в routes.rb есть   `resources :todos`

Comment: у Вас в моделе Todo объявлена ассоциация `belongs_to project`? И в модели Project должна быть ассоциация `has_many todos`

Comment: routes.rb - это файл настройки роутинга. В нём определяется какой экшн какого контроллера будет обрабатывать запрос. Связи моделей определяются в классах моделей.

Comment: Да, в моделях ассоциации объявлены

Comment: Разобрался, большое спасибо, была небольшая ошибка в index.html.erb, нужно было написать `  <% project.todo.each do |todo| %> :D

Comment: @VoltBoy у вас в модели `has_many :todo` что ли? По конвенции там множественное число ожидается.

Comment: Да, все верно, в models/todo.rb has_many :todo было, поправил модели и index.html.erb